# SQL alternative to a View

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I don't really know how to even ask for what i need.
So i try to explain my situation.

I have a rather simple sql query that joins various tables but I need to execute this query with slightly different conditions over and over again.

The execusion time of the query is somewhere around 0.25 seconds.
But all the queries i need to execute take easily 15 seconds.
This is way to long.

What i need is a table or view that holds the query results for me so that i only need to select from this one table instead of joining large tables over and over again.

A view wouldn't really help because it would just execute the same query over and over again. As far as i know.

Is there a way to have something like a view which holds its data as long as its source tables doesn't change ? And will only update and execute the query if it is really necessary?

Comment: Have your tried indexed views? You could create an indexed view that can cater to all your different conditions and then the select queries can pick the subset it needs...

Comment: Depending on your DBMS you might want to look into materialized views. Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? You should also show us the queries you have to run.

Comment: I work on oracle 11g these materialized views seem promising.

Comment: I quess i will give the materialized views a try these sound exactly like what i had in mind thanks so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you described very good fits to

> materialized view

usage with fast refresh on commit. However your query need to be eligible for fast refresh.

Another way to use

> result_cache

- it is automatically invalidates when one of the source tables is changed. I would try both to decide which one suites better for this particular task.

Comment: thanks i will give both methods a try and see which on performs best.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest table-valued functions for this purpose.  Defining such a function requires coding in PL/SQL, but it is not that hard if the function is based on a single query.

You can think of such functions as a way of parameterizing views.

[Here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php) is a good place to start learning about them.

Comment: Hi, isn't the problem with these table functions that they will execute every time i call them ? this is basically what i try to avoid.

Comment: @ZSchneidi . . . A table valued function should be optimized for the input.  A materialized view incurs the overhead of maintaining the data set when there are changes in the underlying tables.  Also, it is not optimized for a single query using one set of parameters.